# Audio-video stream with use Liquidsoap

Tags: video, stream, liquidsoap

I have a problem with audio-video stream to IceCast2 Server using Liquidsoap. 
Using example code with use picture in JPG format - it works!

```
<code>s = single("/mnt/dysk1/all/test.gif")
output.icecast(
  %ogg(%theora),
  host="localhost",
  port=8000,
  password="*****",
  mount="/test1.ogg",
  name="Test1",
  description="Testing...",
  url=" ",
  s)</code>
```

Example code with example use audio-video in AVI format and audio-video in MP4 format and audio-video in WEBM format- did not work!

```
<code>s = single("/mnt/dysk1/all/test.avi")
output.icecast(
  %ogg(%theora, %vorbis),
  host="localhost",
  port=8000,
  password="*****",
  mount="/test1.ogg",
  name="Test1",
  description="Testing...",
  url=" ",
  s)</code>
```

You receive the following error message:

```
Invalid value at line 1, char 12-36: 
Could not get a valid media file of kind {audio=2;video=1;midi=0} from "/mnt/dysk1/all/test.avi".
```

Example code with example use audio-video in OGV format - did not work!

```
<code>s = single("/mnt/dysk1/all/test.ogv")
output.icecast(
  %ogg(%theora, %vorbis),
  host="localhost",
  port=8000,
  password="*****",
  mount="/test1.ogg",
  name="Test1",
  description="Testing...",
  url=" ",
  s)</code>
```

You receive the following error message:

```
notification: Speex header too small
notification: Speex header too small
notification: Speex header too small
notification: Speex header too small
```

My distribution is the Linux Raspbian. 
Liquidsoap installation from the repository

```
apt-get install liquidsoap liquidsoap-plugin-all
```

I apologize for my low level of English proficiency. 
Please help me.